# Resizing a TextBox so font is correctly displayed when Control is resized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, viewbox

Im looking to style a TextBox so that when the size of my control changes the TextBox and/or font is resized so that it correctly displays.

I almost have it working.

My Style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ViewBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Example code:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ViewBoxTextBox}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="2" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

Below is a screenshot of the 3 conditions.

[image: Screenshots]

In the third screenshot when i reduce the height of my control the TextBox font is correctly decreasing in size but the the TextBox width is decreasing and not taking up the whole available width.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set the Stretch property of the ViewBox to Fill.

Comment: @mm8 That does work to fix the width to the maximum, however it has prevented the font size from decreasing inside the textbox, instead it is just squished in height.

Comment: Easiest route, slap it in a `ViewBox`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it works to make a basic override of the Control's Template, but in this case you need more fine grained control over the text inside the TextBox.  To do that I got a copy of TextBox's default Template and then made some modifications.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="ViewBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ActualWidth}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                                          Focusable="false" 
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                          Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The ContentHost is now wrapped within a ViewBox which will correctly scale the text, and the Border will scale based on the more normal size constraints.  I tried it under several different scenarios and it worked for the cases I attempted.  Hopefully it works for your usage.